# Pandas GroupBy column value and create list of fixed size from values in each group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

First post, did my best to describe my issue. Let me know if I need to adjust anything with respect to format or clarify any aspects of the problem. Thanks!

I have large Pandas data frame of movie ratings and I need to create user ratings vectors for each movie. I am looking for a way to this more efficiently (using pandas / numpy operations or vectorization??) in order to process the 26M rows or user, movie rating pairs in my dataset.

The data frame of movie ratings looks like this:
Input:

```
movieId userId  rating
1            1     1.0
1            2     4.5
1            5     5.0
1            8     5.0
1           10     5.0
2            1     2.0
2            3     4.5
2            5     5.0
2            6     3.0
2            8     4.0
```

Output:

Key = MovieID

Value = Dense array of ratings for each user, 0 means the user did not rate the movie.

```
{
   0:[1.0, 4.5, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0]
   1:[2.0, 0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
}
```

I currently have this function which performs the job correctly but is not scaling which the amount of data I need to process.
`user_rating_by_movie` is a global pandas data frame matching the form of the input.
`num_users` is the largest user id to serve as the length of the vector.

```
def build_rating_vector_for_movie(movie_id, num_users):   
    rating_vector = [0] * num_users
    movie_group = user_rating_by_movie.get_group(movie_id)

    for u, r in zip(movie_group.userId.values, movie_group.rating.values):
        rating_vector[u - 1] = r

    movie_user_ratings[movie_id] = rating_vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @Wen

```
pd.crosstab(df.movieId, df.userId, df.rating, aggfunc='mean').fillna(0).T.to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{1: [1.0, 4.5, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0],
 2: [2.0, 0.0, 4.5, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0]}
```

- Note:

  The 'mean' in aggfunc should be meaningless if one rating per user for each movie.

Comment: comparison of run times using Jupiter %timeit magic command:
Wen's solution:
1 loop, best of 3: 6.13 s per loop.


Scott Boston's solution:
1 loop, best of 3: 902 ms per loop.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By using `pivot`+`reindex`

```
df.pivot('movieId','userId',values='rating').reindex(columns=list(range(1,11))).fillna(0)
Out[219]: 
userId    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
movieId                                                  
1        1.0  4.5  0.0  0.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  0.0  5.0
2        2.0  0.0  4.5  0.0  5.0  3.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  0.0
```

For build the dict add `.T.to_dict('list')` at the end

```
df.pivot('movieId','userId',values='rating').reindex(columns=list(range(1,11))).fillna(0).T.to_dict('list')
Out[223]: 
{1: [1.0, 4.5, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0],
 2: [2.0, 0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]}
```